# pytest unittest spark java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, pytest, python-unittest

Running unit testing using pytest for pyspark code. Code snippet sample from code given below. Looks like spark runtime or hadoop runtime libraries expected , but i thought unit testing does not really need spark libraries. Just pyspark python package is enough because tools like Jenkins won't have spark runtime installed. Please guide

```
    def read_inputfile_from_ADLS(self):
    try:
        if self.segment == "US":
            if self.input_path_2 is None or self.input_path_2 == "":
                df = self.spark.read.format("delta").load(self.input_path)
            else:
                df = self.spark.read.format("delta").load(self.input_path_2)
    except Exception as e: 
        resultmsg = "error reading input file"
```

Pytest code

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch,MagicMock , Mock

class TestInputPreprocessor:
    inpprcr = None
    dataframe_reader = 'pyspark.sql.readwriter.DataFrameReader'

    def test_read_inputfile_from_ADLS(self,spark,tmp_path):
        self.segment = 'US'
        self.input_path_2 = tmp_path 
        with patch(f'{self.dataframe_reader}.format', MagicMock(autospec=True)) as 
           mock_adls_read:
            self.inpprcr.read_inputfile_from_ADLS()
            assert mock_adls_read.call_count == 1
```

Error:

```
AssertionError
---------------------------------------------- Captured stderr setup ------------------- 
--------------------------- 
23/07/12 23:58:42 WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see 
https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use 
setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/07/12 23:58:42 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your 
platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue. Have to download winutils.exe and map to HADOOP_HOME , SPARK_HOME to pyspark location in python lib
'C:\Users<networkid>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pyspark'

No need to install Hadoop or Spark on local laptop for unit testing